# Parsing JS with regex python

Tags: javascript, python, regex, json, web-scraping

I have some javascript text to parse with python
There is in js html elemet such variable:

```
this.products = ko.observableArray([#here is some json, #here is some json])
```

observableArray could be an holder for 1 json it will be observableArray({'id': '234234'}) or observableArray(['id': '3123123]), also it can hold infinite number of json per comma like in code pasted higher

how can i get this string with jsons with regexp i have try:

```
regex = re.compile('\n^(.*?)=(.*?)$|,',)
js_text = re.findall(regex, js)
print(js_text)
```

but im getting:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
>       return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string) TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: did you want the id values?

Comment: "Parsing JS with regex" - ***DON'T YOU DARE!!!*** Use a JSON parser instead.

Comment: did you want regex like this `\'id\':\s*\'([0-9]*)\'`?

Comment: What value for `js` causes the exception?

Comment: @user3477950 i need to get this string from large js file , then to parse with json

Comment: @AvinashRaj no, i need to catch the this.products = ko.observableArray([#here is some json, #here is some json])

Comment: @AvinashRaj so i need to get this row not json in array

Answer (score 1):

`js` is not a string nor a buffer. Are you sure that `js` is a string (or a buffer)?

```
# no problem
>>> js = "this.products = ko.observableArray({'id': '234234'})"
>>> js_text = re.findall(regex, js)
>>> print(js_text)
[]

# argument is not a string nor a buffer (in this case None)
>>> js_text = re.findall(regex, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mhawke/virtualenvs/urllib3/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
>>> js_text = re.findall(regex, js)
>>> print(js_text)
[]
```

BTW, it's slightly nicer to call `regex.findall(js)`.

And, there is a (different) problem with your regex pattern.